# Не работает ZenCoding в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Ввожу команду, например

```
form.form-comment#comment>fieldset
```

жму таб, но ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте что Emmet (Zen Coding) [включен в опциях](http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/5977/drt9.png).

Функция работает не во всех типах файлов, убедитесь что вы редактируете поддерживаемый тип файла.

Если всё равно не работает, попробуйте `File` | `Invalidate Caches` и перезапустите PhpStorm. Если это баг, то подробную информацию можно найти в [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446).